# How can I arrange a children's song for choir, to make it more interesting?

Tags: arranging, choir

Our church choir would like to perform some children's songs. (I won't go into the reasons why, right now.) How can I make the songs more interesting?  The kids are so cute when they sing them, that the arrangement doesn't really matter. But with adults singing, I want to add some interest.

I got some ideas from this question [What can I do to make cover song to be more interesting?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/18957/2600)

Any other ideas would be greatly appreciated. We do have a flute, occasionally.

Answer (score 2):

All the usual arranging techniques are at your disposal.  Straightforward harmonisation, quirky or "juicy" re-harmonisation, melody in parts other than the soprano, descants, polyphonic devices...

Don't get OVER-clever though!